# The sample code I got from cpp-netlib won't compile

Tags: c++, network-programming, server, cpp-netlib

```
// Copyright 2009 (c) Tarro, Inc.
// Copyright 2009 (c) Dean Michael Berris <mikhailberis@gmail.com>
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
// (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

//[ hello_world_server_main
/*`
  This is a part of the 'Hello World' example. It's used to
  demonstrate how easy it is to set up an HTTP server.  All we do in
  this example is create a request handler and run the server.
 */
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp>
#include <iostream>


namespace http = boost::network::http;


/*<< Defines the server. >>*/
struct hello_world;
typedef http::server<hello_world> server;

/*<< Defines the request handler.  It's a class that defines two
     functions, `operator()` and `log()` >>*/
struct hello_world {
    /*<< This is the function that handles the incoming request. >>*/
    void operator() (server::request const &request,
                     server::response &response) {
        server::string_type ip = source(request);
        std::ostringstream data;
        data << "Hello, " << ip << "!";
        response = server::response::stock_reply(
            server::response::ok, data.str());
    }
    /*<< It's necessary to define a log function, but it's ignored in
         this example. >>*/
    void log(...) {
        // do nothing
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " address port" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try {
        /*<< Creates the request handler. >>*/
        hello_world handler;
        /*<< Creates the server. >>*/
        server server_(argv[1], argv[2], handler);
        /*<< Runs the server. >>*/
        server_.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
//]
```

I suspect it's something to do with not linking my libraries correctly. This is the error I get when I run make. I can run this example fine off the cpp-netlib folder but when I try to copy that code and put it in my own folder, it doesn't compile.

```
/home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/tools/simple_server_test/simpleServerTest.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    /home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/tools/simple_server_test/simpleServerTest.cpp:56:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::network::http::server<hello_world>::server(char*&, char*&, hello_world&)’
             server server_(argv[1], argv[2], handler);
                                                     ^
    /home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/tools/simple_server_test/simpleServerTest.cpp:56:49: note: candidate is:
    In file included from /home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/tools/simple_server_test/simpleServerTest.cpp:14:0:
    /home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/include/boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp:44:12: note: boost::network::http::server<Handler>::server(const options&) [with Handler = hello_world; boost::network::http::server<Handler>::options = boost::network::http::server_options<boost::network::http::tags::http_server, hello_world>]
       explicit server(options const &options) : server_base(options) {}
                ^
    /home/stanley/cmpt373/textadventure/include/boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp:44:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
    make[2]: *** [tools/simple_server_test/CMakeFiles/simpleServerTest.dir/simpleServerTest.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [tools/simple_server_test/CMakeFiles/simpleServerTest.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Since this example code is from 2009 you might need an older version of boost to get it to compile as is, otherwise you need to fix the problem with the example code, which will require some digging.

Comment: Just a guess: The example code was written for a different version of Boost and not updated since then. Check the Boost bug tracking system and possibly file an according bug yourself.

Comment: I can build and run the example fine from the cpp-netlib folder

Answer (score 1):

Note in the CMakeLists.txt under root directory, there is 1 line for Asio

```
include_directories(deps/asio/asio/include)
```

add it to your project, then it will work